# PHP count variable outside a while loop does not increment

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to select a couple of questions from questions table randomly. But, I want to echo a counter in ascending order as the I print out the questions using a while loop. But the counter variable is not incrementing. I do not know where I am going wrong.

```
<php
$sql = "select id, questions, ans1, ans2, ans3, correctAns from questions Order By RAND() Limit 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$result2 = mysql_num_rows($result);
for($x = 1; $x <= $result2; $x++)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$id = $row['id'];
$quest = $row['questions'];
$a1 = $row['ans1'];
$a2 = $row['ans2'];
$a3 = $row['ans3'];
$correct = $row['correctAns'];

echo $x.'<br />';
echo $quest.<br />;
echo $a1.'<br />';
echo $a2.'<br />';
echo $a3.'<br />';
echo $correct.'<br />';
} //end while loop
} // end for loop
?>
```

The counter variable is just echoing 1 as the value throughout the loop.

Comment: This is because your while loop ends after all the rows have been fetched. after all rows are fetched, then $x gets incremented.

Answer (score 2):

You musn't put the counter in a second loop:

```
<?php
$sql = "select id, questions, ans1, ans2, ans3, correctAns from questions Order By RAND() Limit 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql); //ADDED
$x = 1; // ADDED
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) // CHANGED
{
  $id = $row['id'];
  $quest = $row['questions'];
  $a1 = $row['ans1'];
  $a2 = $row['ans2'];
  $a3 = $row['ans3'];
  $correct = $row['correctAns'];

  echo $x.'<br />';
  echo $quest.<br />;
  echo $a1.'<br />';
  echo $a2.'<br />';
  echo $a3.'<br />';
  echo $correct.'<br />';
  x++; //ADDED
} //end while loop
?>
```

In addition, you must pass the query reusult to mysql_fetch_array insteach of the query string.
BTW, mysql_* is deprecated. You should use mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: Guys, I have gone through all your suggestions. But they seem not to work. The point is: I have more than 100 questions in the <questions table>. Each question is fetched randomly by a LIMIT 1. That means, I have put a check that no question should repeat itself. So, each time a question is selected, the counter needs to read a different value. That is where the problem lies. The counter keeps printing the constant value (1) instead of incrementing. Meanwhile, I need to increment the counter variable each time the select statement runs and not the While() loop. Thank you.

Comment: But in your code, the query is executed one time only (in line 3). Where should the counter be updated?

Comment: You see, I have more than a hundred questions. That is why I decided to use a for loop as for(x=1; and x < total rows -1; x++). The loop should start above the while() loop. So that each time, the select statement comes, the x++ will execute.... OKAY! I have an idea. Maybe I should put the for loop above the select statement... what do you think?

Comment: The problem is that you limit your SQL statement to 1 row, but in the for-loop you use the number of rows returned (which is in this case always 1)

Comment: Does it mean that I have to construct an external query without a LIMIT on the rows, then use it to compare with a for loop? Please help more... thannks

Comment: Do you know how much questions you need or is their number varying. If this is the case, where do you get the information from how much questions you need?

Comment: I know how much questions I need. The authority says 100 questions. So, I have also included a limit to the number of questions which a student should answer. On getting to the limit, the script will alert and redirect. Now,  if ( $numRows >= 100 ) from the select query will check whether the students has answered 100 questions or not. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have a loop around the database fetching, consolidate that to one loop, try this:

```
<?php
  $sql = "select id, questions, ans1, ans2, ans3, correctAns from questions Order By RAND()";
  $result = mysql_num_rows($sql);
  $x = 1; // Start the counter
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  {
      echo $x.'<br />'
          .$row['questions'].'<br />'
          .$row['ans1'].'<br />'
          .$row['ans2'].'<br />'
          .$row['ans3'].'<br />'
          .$row['correctAns'].'<br />';
      $x++;
  } //end while loop
?>
```

shortened it for a very slight efficiency increase.

Comment: Guys, I have gone through all your suggestions. But they seem not to work. The point is: I have more than 100 questions in the <questions table>. Each question is fetched randomly by a LIMIT 1. That means, I have put a check that no question should repeat itself. So, each time a question is selected, the counter needs to read a different value. That is where the problem lies. The counter keeps printing the constant value (1) instead of incrementing. Meanwhile, I need to increment the counter variable each time the select statement runs and not the While() loop. Thank you.

Comment: Why didn't you explain all of that in your original question?

Comment: I am sorry, my mistake. I just realised that this is the problem all along and not the while loop. Because the while loop is only loop through the rows of the select query. I am sorry. So, how do I solve this problem please? Thank you!

Comment: rather than executing the query for random 1 row every time, it is better to get all the rows at once and then show them one by one with logic in php. That will be efficient as you need not worry about getting the same row twice and also the DB query will be saved

Comment: HOW? Notice that, the query is random selection of rows. How do you construct this logic please? I cannot figure out any ideas now. Thank you!

Comment: this would depend on the interface or the UI you want to give. If you want to have 1 question every page (just like any online exam) you can maintain an array of all the questions from DB and then show questions just by looping through the array.

Comment: @SaurabhSinha it would be way more efficient they way user3134352 is trying to do. what if they had 3 million questions? thats a LOT of data, limiting the result to a random 1 row is way more efficient. I'll see what I can come up with user3134352

Comment: @iamde_coder Lets be practical.. no one is going to show 1 million question in exam. Secondly if the data is more even then it is better to load the data once rather than losing your user experience in executing query on every page load. And I am not  saying to query the complete row of table, I just told to query the number of question you want to show.

Comment: @iamde_coder you will definelty use LIMIT but limit should not be 1. it should be n (n = number of question to show)

Comment: I really like your unanimous ideas. The reason I am creating a counter variable is just to echo which question number a user is attempting. But that does not mean that the counter is echoing the question as identified by the row 'id'. That is, Normally, using a random row selection, the row id will also be random. But I do not need to echo QNo(id). All I want to echo is a counter variable. So that, even if the random selection picks row 10 as the first question, the counter will be QNo.(1). If it's row 100 as second question, then counter will be QNo(2) etc. Thank you!

Comment: @Saurabh Sinha, I need to display 1 question per page. There is a timer on the page for auto_form_submit() whether or not a user picks an answer. However, if a user selects an answer, the form submits using the onChange event of the control.

Comment: ok! I would suggest to get all the questions at once and create a javascript array. and iterate through the array to just show 1 question at a time. This will save page loads and the user experience will be better.

Comment: @user3134352 if you want i can help you with the code.  But you will have to atleast start writing something. you can contact me on sinha.ksaurabh@gmail.com

Comment: I really want to appreciate your ideas. I want to admit that, I have figured out something. I created another table and passed each selected question. So, I used the num_rows of that new table to find a counter. Thank you all for your contributions.

Answer (score 0):

I want to make you all understand that I appreciate your collective efforts in attempting to solve the challenge that I put forth. However, I have solved the challenge. Below is the source:

```
<?php
// Establish Connection with Database// Select Database
include_once( '../../Connections/QUIZ.php' );
// Specify the query to execute
```

Every student has an app id in the session after login.
For every question the student answers, the app performs an UPDATE in another table u_answer.
We will first of all check whether the student has already answered any questions by performing a select query on the u_answer table.

AS_Id is the student's Id from the session variable.

```
$sql = "select * from u_answer,questions where u_answer.AS_Id = '" . $_SESSION[ 'appID' ] . "' and questions.qid = u_answer.qid";
$result = mysql_query( $sql, $con ) or die( mysql_error() );
$records = mysql_num_rows( $result );

if ( $records < 1 ) {
//create and increment a counter(x) by 1
$x = $records + 1;
```

Perform the original select query for the questions.

```
$sql2 = "select * from questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
else
{
```

Still increment the counter by 1 using the number of records found.

```
$x = $records + 1;
```

This select query below ensures that no students answers a particular question more than 1 time.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT questions.qid, questions.question,questions.ans1, 
questions.ans2, questions.ans3, questons.ans4, questions.correctAns
FROM questions WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM u_answer WHERE u_answer.qid = questions.qid AND u_answer.AS_Id = '" . $_SESSION[ 'appID' ] . "') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";   
$result2 = mysql_query( $sql2 );
```

perform a while loop here at this point.

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result2 ) ) {
$id = $row['id'];
$quest = $row['questions'];
$a1 = $row['ans1'];
$a2 = $row['ans2'];
$a3 = $row['ans3'];
$correct = $row['correctAns'];
```

Print out the extracted data.

```
echo $x.'<br />'; //the counter variable.
echo $quest.<br />;
echo $a1.'<br />';
echo $a2.'<br />';
echo $a3.'<br />';
echo $correct.'<br />';
}
```

Close connection to the database.

```
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

This works for me.